# Have some buttons show only in landscape mode

Tags: android, button, screen-orientation

I want to have specific buttons show only in landscape mode - not to be shown or available in portrait. I have separate xml files for landscape and portrait

I tried using an OrientationEventListener and while it was running, i checked the device orientation to be in landscape - if it was, i called findViewById on it but it crashes due to NullPointer. My code so far:

```
Button landscapeTest;

public boolean isInLandscape() {
int orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
return orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;

OrientationEventListener orientationEventListener = new OrientationEventListener(this, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI) {
@Override
public void onOrientationChanged(int orientation) {
   boolean isInLandscape = isInLandscape();
   if (isInLandscape) {
       landscapeTest = findViewById(R.id.button_landscape);
       landscapeTest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               Log.v("landscapeButton", "I am working!!!");
           }
       });
   }
}
};
```

Expected - when i change the device orientation ( from portrait to landscape ), i should see the button with id button_landscape in the UI and when i tap on it, i should see "I am working!!!" in the logcat

Actual: when i change the device orientation ( form portrait to landscape ), it crashes with NullPointer because it can't find the button.

Comment: Place `landscapeTest = findViewById(R.id.button_landscape);` in `onCreate`. When the orientation changes set the visibility by choosing between `landscapeTest.setVisibility(View.GONE / View.VISIBLE)`

Comment: Best practice to follow is that you can create separate layout file under layout-land folder if you want to show different view in different mode.

Comment: You also want to place your `OnClickListener` in `onCreate`, only handle the visibility when the screen is rotated, not the `OnClickListener`.

Comment: Put the same buttons in the portrait layout, but set theyr visibility to `GONE`

Answer (score 0):

Reason behind crash is that when you change the orientation, Android restarts the Activity. And Calls the `OnCreate()` again.

**Please read** [Handle Runtime Changes](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes)

1) If you want to show different layout on different mode, I would suggest to create separate file for portrait mode(layout/layout.xml) and landscape mode(layout-land/layout.xml) with the same name. So android will handle the orientation change.

2) If you don't want to create two separate layout files and handle it from the class file. Please move your code to `OnCreate()` and check if layout is in Portrait or Landscape from `OnCreate()`. Because `onClickListener` don't belong to  the `onOrientationChanged`. It will also solve the issue of `NullPointerException`. Based on the orientation you can hide/show the button.

Comment: Your first solution will still return a `NullPointerException` as the `Button` will be available in on `layout.xml` (Portrait) and not the other(Landscape). When calling `landscapeTest = findViewById(R.id.button_landscape);` he will still get a `NullPointerException`. In this case, it is better to handle it using visibility.

Comment: You need to put check if the button is null or not. then only you can use `setOnClickListener()` . By using different files Android will handle Orientation Changes, but the null check and implementation you need to handle manually.

Answer (score 0):

Like I mentioned in the comment section. You only want to handle the visibility of your `Button` when the orientation changes.

```
landscapeTest = findViewById(R.id.button_landscape);
```

should be in `OnCreate` as well as your `OnClickListener`.

Here is an example:

```
public class SomeActivity extends Activity {    

Button landscapeTest;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_some);

    landscapeTest = findViewById(R.id.button_landscape);
    landscapeTest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           Log.v("landscapeButton", "I am working!!!");
       }
    });

    OrientationEventListener orientationEventListener = new OrientationEventListener(this, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI) {
    @Override
    public void onOrientationChanged(int orientation) {
        boolean isInLandscape = isInLandscape();
        if (isInLandscape) {
        landscapeTest.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }else{
        landscapeTest.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try This Will help you:**

```
@Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        if(newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            landscapeTest.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            landscapeTest.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
```